# Baptism first name (or confirmation middle name) for special devotion to the Holy Trinity?

Tags: trinity, baptism, intercession-of-saints, confirmation, name

Catholics almost always have first and second names indicating devotion to some saints, expecting special help and intercession from them. I feel, that there is no good saint which can be my patron saint and intercessor and who can I refer in my middle name. Instead I would like to have middle name which indicates my special devotion to the Holy Trinity. Is there such middle name? There is name Trinity, but it is rarely used as a man name (it would be interesting to know the reason). And then there is first name Emmanuel (God is with us, there is also form with one 'm') but I feel that there can be name that is still more closed to the God and that can have some more trinitarian reference. Is there such name for baptism (as the first name) or confirmation (as the middle name)?

Comment: Trinity is a grammatically feminine noun, in European languages possessing grammatical gender, including the original Latin. Also, Jesus is a fairly common Spanish name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Baptism first name (or confirmation middle name) for special devotion to the Holy Trinity?**

Most Catholics baptismal names are generally have their origins from canonized saints, but not always.

> [**Early Christianity and Baptismal Names**](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84091/baptism-first-name-or-confirmation-middle-name-for-special-devotion-to-the-hol)
>
> The Catholic tradition of naming a child after a saint is not new. It is an ancient tradition that carries much significance, and rightly so!
>
> In the 4th century, St. John Chrysostom strongly encouraged parents to choose for their children names of holy men and women known for their strength and virtue, in order that the children might look to them as role models.
>
> Even earlier, St. Dionysius of Alexandria (c. 260) observed, “There are many of the same name as the Apostle John, who on account of their love for him, and because they admired and emulated him, and desired to be loved by the Lord as he was, took to themselves the same name, just as many of the children of the faithful are called Paul or Peter."
>
> Canon Law and the Tradition of Giving Children Christian Names
>
> Many Catholics choose a saint’s name for their child’s first or middle name (or both!). In the past, Canon Law required that parents have a Christian name for the child at Baptism. However, this is no longer a hard-and-fast requirement. In the current code of Canon Law, number 855 simply states:
>
> > “Parents, sponsors, and the pastor are to take care that a name foreign to Christian sensibility is not given.”
>
> This statement is phrased negatively, meaning that, instead of telling parents what they must do, a few names are instead considered “off limits,” while the rest is left to the prayerful reflection of the parents.
>
> For example, it would be rather unsettling for a Catholic to present the name “Lucifer” or “Zeus” for an infant at his baptism, and the priest might question what intention the parents had in giving their child such a name.
>
> That being said, there is a long and beautiful tradition as to why Catholics do present a saintly or biblical name for their child at Baptism, and why those who convert to Catholicism may choose to take an additional name when they are baptized.

Thus the names for ***Baptism*** and for ***Confirmation***, can vary considerably unknown names would not be forbidden by Canon Law, as long as they are not offensive to Christian standards.

That said, it is sometimes seen that children are named after a particular **mystery of our faith**, such as the Assumption of Mary!

Assunta is not that uncommon in Spanish, Portuguese and Italian speaking countries.

> [**Assunta**](https://www.thebump.com/b/assunta-baby-name) as a girl's name is of Latin origin, and the meaning of Assunta is "Assumption (of the Virgin Mary into Heaven)".

As far as a devotional name of children in honour of the Trinity, the name Trinity is sometimes given to girls out of devotion to the Most Holy Trinity.

> [**Paraclete**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraclete) (Greek: παράκλητος, Latin: paracletus) means advocate or helper. In Christianity, the term "paraclete" most commonly refers to the Holy Spirit.
>
> **Etymology**
>
> Paraclete comes from the Koine Greek word παράκλητος (paráklētos). A combination of "para" (beside/alongside) and "kalein" (to call),[1](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84091/baptism-first-name-or-confirmation-middle-name-for-special-devotion-to-the-hol) the word first appears in the Bible in John 14:16. John Muddiman and John Barton further explain the development of the meaning of this term;
>
> The word parakletos is a verbal adjective, often used of one called to help in a lawcourt. In the Jewish tradition the word was transcribed with Hebrew letters and used for angels, prophets, and the just as advocates before God's court. The word also acquired the meaning of 'one who consoles' (cf. Job 16:2, Theodotion's and Aquila's translations; the LXX has the correct word parakletores). It is probably wrong to explain the Johannine parakletos on the basis of only one religious background. The word is filled with a complex meaning: the Spirit replaces Jesus, is an advocate and a witness, but also consoles the disciples.

The name **Paraclete** was somewhat more common in the centuries gone by in honour of the Holy Trinity. It can still be found occasionally, but it is actually not in vogue anymore.

The origins and popularity of the name given from the 16th century to the 19th century can be see in the graph from the following article: [**Popularité du prénom Paraclet**](https://www.geneanet.org/prenom/Paraclet).

As we can see, at one time in history it was a rather common name.

It could be noted that altars and churches dedicated to the Holy Spirit are one of the rarest titles given to altars and churches. Nevertheless they do exist!

***Deusdedit*** is a saint’s name that could stand in the place of the Holy Trinity!

> [**Deusdedit**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deusdedit) or **Deodatus** (literally "God has given") is the name of several ecclesiastical figures of the Middle Ages.

I have one friend in France, who is actually called Deusdedit.

Some names remain somewhat off limit too!

Although it may be seen as off limits to name a child [**Lucifer**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer), there is an historical Bishop who was named Lucifer. Modern Catholics would frown on such usage of this as a baptismal name nowadays.

**Jesus** is not an uncommon name given to boys in Spanish speaking lands.

> The Church of Cagliari celebrated the feast of a Saint Lucifer on the 20th of May. Two Archbishops of Sardinia wrote for and against the sanctity of Lucifer. The Congregation of the Inquisition imposed silence on both parties, and decreed that the veneration of Lucifer should stand as it was. The Bollandists defend this decree of the Congregation ... contending that the Lucifer in question is not the author of the schism, but another Lucifer who suffered martyrdom in the persecution of the Vandals." - John Henry Blunt, [Dictionary of Sects, Heresies, Ecclesiastical Parties, and Schools of Religious Thought](https://books.google.ca/books?id=xOgtAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22%27Dictionary%20of%20Sects,%20Heresies,%20Ecclesiastical%20Parties,%20and%20Schools%20of%20Religious%20Thought%22&ei=LCFvSbHNN4OClQSDgL3LDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%27Dictionary%20of%20Sects%2C%20Heresies%2C%20Ecclesiastical%20Parties%2C%20and%20Schools%20of%20Religious%20Thought%22&f=false) (1874), p. 263.

Comment: Sorry for my incorrect question - but I wanted to find some name for assignment during baptism or confirmation that would indicate my special devotion to the Holy Trinity. I didn't thought about use of 'Baptism' or 'Confirmation' as my first or middle name. Sorry for confusion. Your reply is full of interesting information and it certainly deserves the upvote which I gave. But it is not the answer to my question which appears to be quite confusing, unfortunately.

Comment: @TomR No problem! I will simply make an addendum later, when I get a moment!

Comment: @TomR Made an edit to my post! Please let me know if I can improve it some how?

Comment: Thanks, now it is OK, most exhausting possible review. Especially thanks for Paraclete.